hypergeometric function on Wikipedia
I am not a mathematician, but I recently encountered the hypergeometric function (for the first time) in a paper about gravitational collapse in General Relativity.
According to Wikipedia here, the hypergeometric function is defined in the very first equation as an infinite series.  Immediately following that definition, comes the text "Here $(q)_n$ is the (rising) Pochhammer symbol . . .".
Now, $(q)_n$ is not used in the preceding definition, so is there a mistake here, or is my mathematical understanding at fault?  In other words, "where is here"?
As an aside, is that definition (as it actually appears in the wiki page!) suitable for evaluation, or should I be looking for a mathematical library to provide it?
UPDATE: The GR paper uses non-integral arguments to the function (the first usage is equation (29), but it is used in quite a few places after that).  Does this imply using some sort of "sigma function", rather than the integral Wikipedia equations for $(q)_n$?
UPDATE 2: my problem has now been solved in comments.  If anyone wants to turn them into an answer I can accept and upvote ;)

It is used in the expression $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\frac{z^n}{n!}$. The $q$ is replaced by $a,b,c$.

@MaxChien Sounds like you mean "a, b, c are replaced by q.  So, is the relation $(q)_n = {(a)_n (b)_n} / (c)_n$?  That is certainly not expressed in the article!

No, each $(a)_n$, $(b)_n$, $(c)_n$ is one independent instance of $(q)_n$.

@RandyMarsh after a bit of head-scratching I think I now get it ;)  I think I have a blind spot for "dummy" variables, but it would have been nice for the wiki article to be a bit more explicit!  Does that sound like I understand your point?

The integers $a,b,c$ are input to the function, you pick them. The requirements on them are that $a$ and $b$ are positive or zero, whereas $c$ must be positive. Once you pick the input you have to compute first $(a)_n$, $(b)_n$, $(c)_n$ and then compute $(a)_n (b)_n / (c)_n$, for all non-negative integers $n$. To compute e.g. $(a)_n$ you have to multiply $a$ with the next $n-1$ integers in ascending order, unless $n=1$ in which case $(a)_1=1$.

I can't really tell if you understand or not :) The best way for you to see that you understand would be to compute a few examples. For example for $a=1$, $b=c$ you should get the geometric series $1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$. Or verify with wolfram alpha, for example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=hypergeometric+function+2F1%281%2C2%2C2%2Cz%29

@RandyMarsh OK thanks for your comments so far - I do not think I get it yet ;)  That paper I linked to clearly uses the hypergeometric function with non-integral a, b, c.  I will have to scratch my head some more . . .

Sorry, I made a mistake, $a$, $b$ and $c$ do not have to be integers, it is that $c$ must not be a negative integer. Otherwise the Pochhammer symbol is used in the same way, $(a)_n$ is $a$ multiplied by the next $n-1$ "successors", where by "successor" I mean $a+1$, $a+2$, $\dots$, $a+n-1$.

@m4r35n357 You can think of the notation $(q)_n$ as a function taking two parameters $g(q,n)$. Then the symbols $(a)_n,(b)_n,(c)_n$ can be rewritten using this notation as $g(a,n),g(b,n),g(c,n)$, respectively (this is not standard notation but might help your confusion with dummy variables).

@MaxChien I think I have got my head around it now - I don't mind now that I know that q is a "dummy" or "abstract" function, that is wikipedia's fault for not mentioning it anywhere ;)  Also, my doubt about using "integer factorial"-like expressions with real values has been cleared up by Randy Marsh.  I think I am now good to go, so thanks guys!

In the context of hypergeometric functions, the notation $(q)_n$ is meant to mean the so-called "rising factorial":
$$(q)_n=q(q+1)\dots (q+n-1)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q+k)$$
I detest this notation for two reasons:

I think it is ambiguous and ugly.
It is inconsistent with how this notation is used elsewhere. In most other contexts, $(q)_n$ means the falling factorial, $(q)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(q\color{red}{\boldsymbol -}k)$

Therefore, whenever I am dealing with hypergeometric functions, I like to either explicitly write out the product definition, or, write it compactly using the Gamma function, like this:
$${}_pF_q\left(\begin{matrix}a_1,\dots,a_p \\ b_1,\dots,b_q\end{matrix}\bigg|~z\right):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\prod_{m=1}^p\frac{\Gamma(a_m+k)}{\Gamma(a_m)}\right)\left(\prod_{n=1}^q\frac{\Gamma(b_n)}{\Gamma(b_n+k)}\right)~\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
